# eventInfo.currentTarget.value crashes inside React callback but not in event handler?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, events, state

I'm using React (18.2.0) and I'm trying to create a page where I enter text into a textbox, and the page immediately updates on-page elements using that new text.  The minimum example looks like this:

[image: h1 text says "Welcome I wrote this!"; textbox underneath contains the string "I wrote this"]

The following code works correctly:

```
import React from "react";

class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    name: "INITIAL MESSAGE",
  };

  onChangeEventHandler = (eventInfo) => {
    this.setState((state, props) => ({ name: eventInfo.target.value }))
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App-header">   
          <p>Welcome {this.state.name}</p>
          <input
            type="text"
            value={this.state.name}
            onChange={this.onChangeEventHandler}
          />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

On my way to this solution I tried to do the same  thing except that I used `currentTarget` instead of `target`:

```
this.setState((state, props) => ({ name: eventInfo.currentTarget.value }))
```

*This* version crashes as soon as I try to change the text, complaining about `react-dom.development.js:11340 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'value')`.

It looks like it's crashing while trying to do the currentTarget.value step in the lambda function; doing that step in the event handler function and storing the result into a local works great:

```
  onChangeEventHandler = (eventInfo) => {
    let newName = eventInfo.currentTarget.value

    this.setState((state, props) => { return { name: newName } }); 
  };
```

**My question is this: why does `eventInfo.currentTarget.value` work fine in the event handler function, but crashes when it's in the lambda function (which React calls later as a callback)?**  In particular, it seems like the lambda should be a closure and have access to the eventInfo object.

One last, even more confusing fact:
If I instrument the code as follows, it appears that eventInfo.currentTarget is **null** in both places.  Why does it crash in the lambda but do fine in the function?

```
  onChangeEventHandler = (eventInfo) => {
    console.log("onChangeEventHandler", eventInfo)
    let newName = eventInfo.currentTarget.value
    this.setState((state, props) => { console.log("lambda", eventInfo);  return { name: newName } }); 
    
    //this.setState((state, props) => ({ name: eventInfo.target.value }))
  };
```

Output:

```
log.js:24 [HMR] Waiting for update signal from WDS...
App.js:10 onChangeEventHandler SyntheticBaseEvent {currentTarget: null,_reactName: 'onChange', _targetInst: null, type: 'change', nativeEvent: InputEvent, target: input, …}bubbles: truecancelable: falsedefaultPrevented: falseeventPhase: 3isDefaultPrevented: ƒ functionThatReturnsFalse()isPropagationStopped: ƒ functionThatReturnsFalse()isTrusted: truenativeEvent: InputEvent {isTrusted: true, data: 'a', isComposing: false, inputType: 'insertText', dataTransfer: null, …}target: inputtimeStamp: 5467.5999999940395type: "change"_reactName: "onChange"_targetInst: null[[Prototype]]: Object
App.js:12 lambda SyntheticBaseEvent {currentTarget: null, _reactName: 'onChange', _targetInst: null, type: 'change', nativeEvent: InputEvent, target: input, …}bubbles: truecancelable: falsedefaultPrevented: falseeventPhase: 3isDefaultPrevented: ƒ functionThatReturnsFalse()isPropagationStopped: ƒ functionThatReturnsFalse()isTrusted: truenativeEvent: InputEvent {isTrusted: true, data: 'a', isComposing: false, inputType: 'insertText', dataTransfer: null, …}target: inputtimeStamp: 5467.5999999940395type: "change"_reactName: "onChange"_targetInst: null[[Prototype]]: Object
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is quite a question - my best theory is this:

Since states are async, there's a disconnect between the way `Event.currentTarget` works and how long it's taking to update the state.

Taking a look at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/currentTarget), there's actually a specific section about `Event.currentTarget` which says this:

> Note: The value of event.currentTarget is only available while the
> event is being handled. If you console.log() the event object, storing
> it in a variable, and then look for the currentTarget key in the
> console, its value will be null. Instead, you should either use
> console.log(event.currentTarget) to be able to view it in the console
> or use the debugger statement, which will pause the execution of your
> code thus showing you the value of event.currentTarget.

Given this, my theory is that you're getting the type error because by the time that setState tries to work - `Event.currentTarget` has no value since it's been resolved. As MDN says, it only carries a value for the life of the event which likely expires too fast for setState to work as intended. The true value would then instead be in `Event.target`, as you're seeing.

I suspect the variable part doesn't cause a crash since it's not async and it's able to store the `null` value. They even somewhat mention this in the above block quote which would explain why your instrumentation shows null.